# Problem with RegionMember

Tags: functions, bugs, geometry, computational-geometry

I think there is potentially a bug in `RegionMember` function, particularly in the `RegionMember[reg]` form.  Can you evaluate the example code below in other versions and add the `bug` tag with the question. (*evaluated in Mathematica 12.3.1 in windows 10*).

```
reg = Rectangle[{0., 0.2}, {13.5, 15.65}];
pt = {-1.6*^-6, 4.3};
RegionMember[reg, pt]
RegionMember[reg][pt]
```

Comment: Confirmed on mac.

Comment: @SHuisman thanks ! reporting it to support.

Comment: I also submitted it, but through a different portal.

Comment: One workaround is `SignedRegionDistance[reg][pt] <= 0`.

Comment: A workaround using distance to test membership is ok for closed regions, as this rectangle example. But can be misleading for boundary points of open regions. E.g., SignedRegionDistance[ImplicitRegion[x < 1, x]][{1}] is 0, but the point 1 isn't a member of that region.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround:

```
reg = Rationalize[Rectangle[{0., 0.2}, {13.5, 15.65}]];
pt = Rationalize[{-1.6*^-6, 4.3}];RegionMember[reg, pt]
```

> `False`

```
RegionMember[reg][pt]
```

> `False`

Comment: It's enough only `reg = Rationalize[Rectangle[{0., 0.2}, {13.5, 15.65}]];`